# SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. The instrumentation process cannot be initialized error with Appium 1.15.1 Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jenkins, appium

I had a problem with my automation testing using Jenkins, I got this error stacktrace from my Jenkins Console like this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-D0GT2LN', ip: '10.0.20.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-D0GT2LN', ip: '10.0.20.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at Tester.FullTesting.openApps(FullTesting.java:463)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at Tester.FullTesting.openApps(FullTesting.java:463)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-D0GT2LN', ip: '10.0.20.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Tester.FullTesting.openApps(FullTesting.java:463)
```

My Appium version v1.15.1

When I test my code with eclipse its work fine. I thought this error might be I duplicate called selenium.

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Appium version?

Comment: My Appium version v1.15.1

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-D0GT2LN', ip: '10.0.20.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\william tanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

...implies that the *AndroidDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* through *Appium*.

---

Some more information from the server-side logs (Appium logs) would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, as per the discussion [Error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12607) this issue is observed with [appium](/questions/tagged/appium) *v1.11* and above, where as in version *v1.10.1* there is no such issue. Presumably the server-side logs (Appium logs) would contain the following *logs messages* related to **UiAutomator2**:

```
[UiAutomator2] 'skipServerInstallation' is set. Attempting to use UIAutomator2 server from the device
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 60000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[debug] [Instrumentation] android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

PThe possible reason is, the *UiAutomator2* is not installed on the device or may be the server installation is disabled explicitly.

---

### Solution

A easier solution would have been to upgrade/downgrade *UIAutomator2* inside Appium but you can't do that since *UIAutomator2* has dependency on other modules.

So, the solution is to downgrade the whole Appium package. As an alternative, you can change the emulator/simulator on the device you are running your tests as well. At times uninstalling the `Appium Settings` app from the device and restarting the *Appium* process aslo solves the issue.